# Magento 2: customize price Configurable Product

Tags: magento2, configurable-product

I need to customize the price of my configurable product in order to show the donation on every purchase.
Basically I have a configurable product with size and color and instead of showing the regular price, I wanna show the real price subtracted the donation that we do.

Example: price = $120
I wanna show $110 + $10 donation. And of course I wanna show the same thing on the checkout page.

How can I do that?

Thanks and Happy new year!

Comment: you can create eav attribute of product named "donation" with Int type and default value 0(Zero). Then override product detail and checkout page by getting donation attribute value

Comment: Uhm can you please elaborate better your answer? Thanks?